# How do I forward an email from a Label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

How do I forward an email from a folder/label in Gmail?
I have googled this question, checked similar questions, but can only see answers related to forwarding folders.
I can only see options to archive, delete, snooze & mark as read/unread.

Comment: So sorry, just found out I should have actually opened the email first.

Comment: Welcome. I hope I understood your question right. I think that when you refer to folders, you mean `Labels`. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. These are the options given **when you look at the left hand side on the top of the `Inbox` or your message**.

[image]

You have to look somewhere else.
You have to **open your message and click the 3 little horizontal dots found on the top, right hand corner of the message**.

[image: dots]

You can also find the `Forward` action on the **bottom of your message**.

[image]